# Get 2 items by one fields and other by chronological

Tags: sql, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a model:

```
class Car(models.Model):
   price = models.IntegerField()
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   ....
```

I want to create Queryset where I get a list where 2 first elements will be Car with biggest price and other by chronological created_at.

I will be grateful for any proposition like a just a SQL or Queryset. Would be nice to have it with one request to db.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first two cars with the highest price

```
q1 = Car.objects.order_by('price')[:1]
```

To get rest with the created_at order

```
qs2 = Car.objects.exclude(id__in=qs)
```

You will have two query sets and you can utilize both.

**UPDATE:**

```
q = q1.union(q2)
```

now, `q` is a queryset and no query has yet been made to the database and you can perform any task related to pagination etc.

Comment: Yes, its easy, but I want to have one queryset and request to db. Also it will be used on ModelViewSet so it will be have List with pagination.